# UPDATE query updates all the data

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-update

There is something that I do not understand, to see if someone could help me.

How is it possible that in a statement like the one I indicate updates all the data of a field, even having an inner clause?

```
update temp_sq05 
set tipoproynew =(
  SELECT
    temp_sq06.TP
  FROM
    temp_sq05 ts   
  INNER JOIN temp_sq06  
    ON temp_sq05.te_cod = temp_sq06.tecodmg 
    and temp_sq05.tipoproynew IS NULL
)
```

Comment: It's possible because your `UPDATE` statement doesn't have a `WHERE` clause to limit the scope of the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery that you use to update the column `tipoproynew` should be correlated to the table `temp_sq05` and this can't be done with the join.
Try this:

```
UPDATE temp_sq05 AS t5  
SET tipoproynew = (
  SELECT t6.TP
  FROM temp_sq06 AS t6  
  WHERE t6.tecodmg = t5.te_cod  
)
WHERE t5.tipoproynew IS NULL;
```

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you could use the `UPDATE...FROM...` syntax:

```
UPDATE temp_sq05 AS t5 
SET tipoproynew = t6.TP
FROM temp_sq06 AS t6  
WHERE t5.te_cod = t6.tecodmg AND t5.tipoproynew IS NULL;
```

Comment: ohh; Thank you very much forpas ,,,, you have saved my life ,, I did not know where I had the fault or how to tackle the problem; I couldn't see it anywhere. I still have a lot to learn from the teachers